# How to get a variable to actually show in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So basically I am practising using Tkinter and I was going to make a little clicker game based on anime. I have researched loads, however, no matter what I try the text saying how many RC cells I have won't show anything at all. please keep it simple as I'm still new to coding.

```
from tkinter import *
rcc=1

x=1


#click function
def click():
global rcc
rcc=rcc+1
return rcc

while x==1:
 rccc=str(rcc)
 window=Tk()
 window.title("my click game boi")
 rc=StringVar()
 rc.set=(rccc)
 window.configure(background="black")
 ##### my photo
photo1=PhotoImage(file="kanekipic.gif")
Label (window, image=photo1, bg='black') .grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)
Button(window, text="eat", width=3, command=click) .grid(row=3, column=0, 
sticky=W)


Label1=Label(window, textvariable=rc, bg="red", fg="white") .grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=S)

print (rcc)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is x? it is assigned 1 at the beginning and does not change. Thus the loop will continue forever.

Comment: x is to make the loop continue forever because I tried putting it like that in hopes it would allow the label to change everytime it ran through the code. however, it doesn't work even with the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution (in the sense that it preserves the desired goal and is "kept simple"), I came up with is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from tkinter import *

rcc = 1

def click():
    global rcc
    rcc += 1
    rc.set(rcc)
    print('rcc was increased to {}'.format(rcc))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Tk()
    window.title("my click game boi")
    window.configure(background='black')

    rc = IntVar()

    photo1 = PhotoImage(file="kanekipic.gif")
    Label(window, image=photo1, bg='black').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)
    Button(window, text="eat", width=3, command=click).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
    Label(window, textvariable=rc, bg="red", fg="white").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=S)

    window.mainloop()
```

Whenever you click on the `eat` button, the counter will be increased.

Comment: Please accept my answer if it is correct to close this topic (click on the checkmark to the left of my post)